# BeautifulSoup - взять из ссылки только нужные мне фрагменты

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, bs4, web-scraping

Как мне взять из ссылки "2701823" 
https://kaspi.kz/shop/p/birjusa-m132-seryi-2701823/?c=750000000 
(ссылки будут меняться)?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

headers = {'accept': '*/*',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) snap Chromium/78.0.3904.108 Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}
base_url = 'https://kaspi.kz/shop/c/smartphones/?q=%3Acategory%3ASmartphones&page=1'


def kaspi_parser(base_url, headers):
    products = []
    urls = []
    urls.append(base_url)
    product_pages = []
    product_pages.append('https://kaspi.kz')
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers=headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
        try:
            pagination = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'pagination__el'})
            count = int(pagination[-2].text)
            for i in range(1, count + 50):
                url = f'https://kaspi.kz/shop/c/smartphones/?q=%3Acategory%3ASmartphones&page={i}'
                if url not in urls:
                    urls.append(url)
        except:
            pass

    for url in urls:
        request = session.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
        divs = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'item-card__info'})
        for div in divs:
            try:
                href = div.find('a', 'ddl_product_link')['href']
                id = div.find('a', class_=re.compile('-id'))
                print(href)
                print(id)
            except:
                pass

    else:
        print('ERROR')
    return products
kaspi_parser(base_url, headers)
```

Comment: `ссылки будут меняться` добавьте в вопрос больше вариантов ссылок, чтобы точно был известен шаблон

Comment: там в ссылки примерно такие же https://kaspi.kz/shop/p/lg-ga-b379-slul-serebristyi-2702277/?c=750000000 меняются цифры которые мне нужны вот например как тут 2702277

Comment: и конечно название товара но перед цифрой - а после /?

Comment: `^.*-([0-9]+)\/[^\/]+$` - https://regex101.com/r/xSg6le/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простенькая регулярка для вытаскивания чисел из ссылки:

```
import re

items = [
    'https://kaspi.kz/shop/p/birjusa-m132-seryi-2701823/?c=750000000',
    'https://kaspi.kz/shop/p/birjusa-m134-seryi-2701321/?c=750000000',
    'https://kaspi.kz/shop/p/birjusa-m134-seryi-1111321/',
]

for url in items:
    match = re.search('-(\d+)/', url)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))

# 2701823
# 2701321
# 1111321
```

Comment: спасибо работает ))))

Comment: @Birzhan, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)